# How to make a transition in height without knowing the height before?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

I want to make a transition of height in CSS, but I noticed that I have to adjust the height statically so that it works.

Here is my code working with static height:

```
<!-- HTML --->
<div class="content show">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <label>Lastname
            <input type="text" name="lastname">
        </label>
        <label>Firstname
            <input type="text" name="firstname">
        </label>
    </form>
</div>

/* CSS */

.content{
    overflow:hidden;
}

.content.show{
    height:433px !important;       <<---------  //I would not define this height
    transition:0.5s;
    -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
}

.content.hidden{
    height:60px;
    transition:0.5s;
    -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
}
```

Here is the code I want to be with an automatic height:

```
<!-- HTML --->
<div class="content show">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <label>Lastname
            <input type="text" name="lastname">
        </label>
        <label>Firstname
            <input type="text" name="firstname">
        </label>
    </form>
</div>

/* CSS */

.content{
    overflow:hidden;
}

.content.show{
    height:auto !important;     <<<----------
    transition:0.5s;
    -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
}

.content.hidden{
    height:60px;
    transition:0.5s;
    -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
}
```

Someone would have an idea how to run this code?
I specify that I do not want to use javascript.

Comment: So what will trigger the animation?

Comment: The best I know of is to set the transition on max-height, and leave height to auto; but it is far from perfect

Comment: @sheriffderek I have a form that appears on a page with a Close button. When you click the button, the form should be hidden using a transition in height and allow display only the title of the form

Comment: So if you don't want to use javaScript - then how are you planning on triggering that from a button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `height` changes without your **CSS** knowing it, I am afraid that it is impossible. The animation has to know the `height` to use.

Here is the documentation of w3c :
http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#two-d-transform-functions for the transitionY() which has to have a *translation-value* `translateY() = translateX( <translation-value> )`, and this *translation-value* must be known "statically" (so if you want it dynamic, you have to do it with **Javascript**. Here is the documentation of the *transition-value* http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#svg-transform-value

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you can't. There are two options though. You can trick it with max height. Try `max-height: 0;` and `max-height: $some-amount-a-little-taller-then-you-want;` The other would be to use some javaScript. even though you said you didn't want to. Maybe something like this: http://code-tricks.com/jquery-animate-to-auto-height/

```
.thing {
    border: 1px solid red;
    max-height: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all .5s linear;
}

.thing:hover {
    max-height: 30em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you do not know the `height` before. CSS is not powerful to make his assertions alone. I think you're forced to use JavaScript and / or Jquery.